# ¿Se puede optimizar este código con la estructura case en Ruby?

Tags: ruby

¿Se puede optimizar este código con la estructura case en Ruby?

o ¿de alguna otra forma?

```
v1 = 'a'
v2 = 'b'
v3 = 'c'

if v1 == v2 && v1 == v3
   p "v1, v2 y v3 son iguales"
elsif v1 == v2 && v1 != v3
   p "v1 y v2 son iguales, v3 es diferente" 
elsif v1 != v2 && v2 == v3
   p "v2 y v3 son iguales, v1 es diferente" 
elsif v1 == v3 && v2 != v3
   p "v1 y v3 son iguales, v2 es diferente" 
elsif v1 != v2 && v1 != v3 && v2 != v3
   p "v1, v2 y v3 son diferentes" 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no hay mucha *optimización* que se pueda hacer, utilizar un `case` resultaría en un rendimiento prácticamente igual, sin embargo sí podrías reducir el número de evaluaciones que se hacen eliminando los `&&`:

```
v1 = 'a'
v2 = 'b'
v3 = 'c'

if v1 == v2
  if v1 == v3
    p "v1, v2 y v3 son iguales"
  else
    p "v1 y v2 son iguales, v3 es diferente"
  end
else
  if v2 == v3
    p "v2 y v3 son iguales, v1 es diferente" 
  elsif v1 == v3
    p "v1 y v3 son iguales, v2 es diferente" 
  else
    p "v1, v2 y v3 son diferentes"
  end
end
```

Anidando `if`s utilizarías un máximo de 3 evaluaciones, mientras que en tu código actual podrías requerir hasta 11 evaluaciones. Sin embargo este código es mucho menos legible que el que tienes, el cual deja muy claro lo que hace y, en la realidad, es muy poco probable que esta optimización realmente tenga un efecto en tu aplicación.